# GSM module with Android on BeagleBoard

Tags: android, gsm, beagleboard

I'm using http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9427 as GSM module. I've built for FTDI and generic usb-serial driver. Everytime I try to `pppd call GPRS` I'll get `pppd: connect script failed`.
The commands executed were:
1. pppd /dev/ttyUSB0
2. netcfg ppp0 up
3. pppd call gprs

gprs script:
`/dev/ttyUSB0

460800

crtscts

modem

noauth

debug

nodetach

usepeerdns

noipdefault

defaultroute

user ""

0.0.0.0:0.0.0.0

connect '/system/bin/chat -s -v -f /system/etc/ppp/gprs-connect-chat'`  `

gprs-connect-chat script:
`TIMEOUT         15

ABORT           "DELAYED"

ABORT           "BUSY"

ABORT           "ERROR"

ABORT           "NO DIALTONE"

ABORT           "NO CARRIER"

TIMEOUT         40

''              \rAT

OK              ATZ

OK              "ATQ0 V1 E0 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0"

OK              AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","Singtel"

OK              ATDT*99#
CONNECT`

Comment: You must give more details, program outputs, etc. in order to get an answer.